# How to center align text in span bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a span in an input group, with a min-width of 6rem. This causes the text to not be center aligned, as spans are usually only a wide as the text itself.

```css
.input-group-text {
  min-width: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col input-group mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <span class="input-group-text">Ending</span>
  <button>...</button>
</div>
```

We can see the "Ending" text is not center aligned in the result.
Adding 'text-center' to the span does not work, nor does adding 'text-align: center;' to the input-group CSS work.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you set a width on your `col` class, then `text-align` should work. Has to know where to center first.

Comment: `<span>` elements will only be as wide as the content contained within. Changing to `<div>` will allow you to center the text because the `<div>` element will fill all of the space provided by it's parent.

Comment: setting a col size in the parent div did not work unfortunately @Kameron

Comment: nor did changing to div work for 'text-center' unfortunately, text is still left justified @daddygames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you center element using flex

```html
<span class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center input-group-text">
    Ending
</span>
```

is it what you want?

Comment: This looks good, but you have a couple classes there that aren't necessary. You don't need `d-flex` because you're already in a flex context, and `align-items-center` would handle vertical alignment of the flex row. Just `justify-content-*` does the job.

Comment: yes you are right, when I want to center something I always come up with `flex`, `align-items` and `justify-center` for safe centering,  your code looks simpler

Comment: On big projects brevity is important. :)

Comment: thank you! justify-content-center worked, all the different ways to center get so confusing for me

Answer (score 0):

Using the `justify-content-center` class on the span seems to work. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex.

```css
.input-group-text {
  min-width: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col input-group mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <span class="input-group-text justify-content-center">Beginning</span>
  <button>...</button>
</div>

<div class="col input-group mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <span class="input-group-text justify-content-center">Ending</span>
  <button>...</button>
</div>
```